# Linking error when I include dnn module in opencv 3.1.0

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I tried to use dnn module of Opencv 3.1.0 to do some object detection, which I follow tutorial here: [Opencv dnn module tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html#gsc.tab=0)

From my understanding, extra module, which contain dnn module, should be built with Opencv source. So I follow this tutorial: [Build Opencv with Extra Modules](https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/building-and-installing-opencv-3-0-on-windows-7-64-bit/).

However, when I try to compile this simple code in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013,

```
#include <opencv2\dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;

void main() {

}
```

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: WithDnnModule, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  DnnTest.cpp
>   1>DnnTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall cv::String::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@String@cv@@AAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::String::~String(void)" (??1String@cv@@QAE@XZ)
>   1>C:\Rescourse\Project\opencvdnn\WithDnnModule\Debug\WithDnnModule.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

If I don't include opencv2\dnn.hpp, I can build the code successfully.

Please help me out.

Comment: you need to link the opencv .lib

Comment: You mean something like opencv_core310d.lib and opencv_dnn310d.lib? I'm sure I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar problem. It turned out that I was trying to link against the x64 opencv lib/dll but my project was set to x86.

Comment: LOL. You help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the correct library.
This include will give you all of OpenCV libraries:

## include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

Answer (score 0):

Try installing OpenCV 3.10 using [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) in a custom directory on your machine. It doesn't matter if you have any other instance of OpenCV installed.

I suppose you will install it in  `/home/ubuntu/opencv310`:

For installation you should run the following command by putting contrib directory somwhere like `/home/ubuntu/opencv_contrib`:

```
ccmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/opencv310 -DWITH_CUDA=ON  -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/ubuntu/opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

and you are going to run [this example](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html#gsc.tab=0):

```
g++ -I/home/ubuntu/opencv310/include -L/home/ubuntu/opencv310/lib  caffe.cpp  -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_core -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_face -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc  -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_photo -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_text -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_dnn -o caffe
```

Now you can run it using `./caffe` .